# Is it possible to calculate the span factor to get minimal height?

Tags: tables, tabu

If i have a tabu table i can specify the `X` parameter with a optional span factor `X[f]`. If i have a big table with varying content length for each cell, i would like to achieve the minimum height of the table by adjusting the `f` span factors of specific `X`.

For example the first and last `X` could be variable but the rest `X` should get the same span factor: `{X[2]XXXXXX[1.5]}`

I can do this manually for hours and holding a ruler against the display to see if i make progress ;)

**Is it possible to automatically calculate the span factor for specific `X` to get a minimal height of the table?**

### Example for tests

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {XXXXXXX}
        \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Fix} & \textbf{Fix} & \textbf{Fix} & \textbf{Fix} & \textbf{Fix} & \textbf{Variable} \\
        bar bar bar bar bar bar & bar & bar & bar & bar & bar & bar bar \\
        bar bar & bar bar & bar & bar & bar & bar & bar bar bar bar bar \\
        bar bar & bar bar bar bar bar & bar & bar & bar & bar & bar  \\
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could use tabulary instead, which is designed to allocate wider columns to columns with more content.

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot to mention the important part: Only the span factor of specific X should be variable. See the edited question.

Comment: please fix your example to be a complete document (so i don't have to guess where you defined `\midrule`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabu` basically uses a variant of `tabularx` column algorithm, but here you want `tabulary` which allocates wider columns to columns with more content.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{*{7}{J}}
        \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} &
        \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} \\
        \midrule
        bar bar bar bar bar bar & bar & bar & bar & bar & bar & bar bar \\
        bar bar & bar bar & bar & bar & bar & bar & bar bar bar bar bar \\
        bar bar & bar bar bar bar bar & bar & bar & bar & bar & bar  \\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabulary}

\bigskip


    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{J*{5}{p{.8cm}}J}
        \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} &
        \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} & \textbf{Test} \\
        \midrule
        bar bar bar bar bar bar & bar & bar & bar & bar & bar & bar bar \\
        bar bar & bar bar & bar & bar & bar & bar & bar bar bar bar bar \\
        bar bar & bar bar bar bar bar & bar & bar & bar & bar & bar  \\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabulary}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: any columns that you do not want allocated automatically just use `p{2cm}` instead of `J`

Comment: Could you edit your example so it shows only the first and last variable? Would be helpfull for me. My problem with the p{2cm} solution is, that then the first and the last only have the rest of the length variable for them but not the total length. What is need is that the first and the last are totally variable and all between just get the same length from what is left.

Comment: @spen you need an extra constraint _somewhere_ if the first and last are totally variable then they could fill the full space so the other columns would get nothing, specifying a fixed width seems as good as anything

Comment: You are right. I somehow didn't thought about that. Thank you for the example.